# jQuery check the second anchor tag href and assign that to div on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have my markup like this

```
<div class="links">
  <ul>
      <li>
          <a class="test"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a href="http:example.com" target="_blank" class="test" ></a>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Like this I have almost 30 divs. Now here you can inside ul there are 2 li are presentand inside each div I have diffrent page link inside 2nd anchor tag. So here I want that when someone clicks on the div then it will redirect to the second anchor tag href link page. So can someone kindly tell me how to do this?

Comment: Why are you answering this question... Like this, its no help, you just doing the job for him...

Answer (score 1):

Use like this:

```
$('.links').on('click',function(e){
e.preventDeafult();
window.location.href = $(this).find('li:last-child').children('a').attr('src');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this

```
 $(".links").click(function () {
    window.location.href = $(this).find("a:eq(1)").attr("src");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call class with the link, test99 and then use jquery to get it like so...

```
$(".links").click(function() {

  $("#display").text($(this).find(".test5").attr("href"));

});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/sezitozu/1/

Answer (score 0):

I think this would helped you.

Try this :

```
$('.links').each(function(){    
var link = $(this).find('ul > li:nth-child(2) > a').attr('href');
    $(this).attr('onClick', 'window.open("' +link + '")');
});
```

[See in JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ZFBP/7/)

Your Question not clear for me. So, I post another solution on-behalf of your statement:

> **here I want that when someone clicks on the div then it will redirect to the second anchor tag href link page.**

```
$('.links').click(function(){      
var link = $(this).nextAll('div.links').find('ul > li:nth-child(2) > a').attr('href');
    if(link != undefined){
     window.location.href =link;
    }
});
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4ZFBP/10/)